# Has anyone gotten Xamarin-Sidebar, MVVMCross & Storyboards to work together?

Tags: menu, xamarin, storyboard, mvvmcross, flyout

I've tried all permutations I can find on the web and just can't seem to get this to work.

I have my iOS app UI defined within a storyboard and the MVVM framework is mostly MVVMCross with some sprinkling of ReactiveUI thrown in for flavor.

I have a RootViewController defined where I generate the SideBarController that is attached to the AppDelegate as so:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window { 
        get;
        set;
    }

    public AppDelegate ()
    {
    }

    public SidebarController SidebarController { get; set; }
    public override void FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application)
    {
        var presenter = new MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter (this, Window);
        var setup = new Setup (this, presenter);

        setup.Initialize ();

        var startUp = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart> ();
        startUp.Start ();
    }
}
```

And in the RootViewController I have:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        if (ViewModel == null)
            return;

        var appDelegate = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate;      
        appDelegate.SidebarController = new SidebarController (this, 
            (UIViewController)this.CreateViewControllerFor<LoginViewModel>(), 
            (UIViewController)this.CreateViewControllerFor<SideMenuViewModel>());
        appDelegate.SidebarController.MenuWidth = 250;
        appDelegate.SidebarController.ReopenOnRotate = false;
        appDelegate.SidebarController.MenuLocation = SidebarController.MenuLocations.Right;
    }
```

After the user has a successful login they are then navigated to a landing page that has a burger button on it. Once the user clicks the burger button the side menu isn't show but all tracing before and after the `ToggleMenu()` call gets executed. I'm racking my brain trying to get this to work but after 3 days I think I may have given myself a concussion.

Has anyone tried to get this combo working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after looking over the code that [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4222823/martijn) posted and then actually doing some snooping through his previous posts, I decided that it would be best to create my own MvxViewPresenter and so far it works.

```
public class SideBarControllerTouchViewPresenter : MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter
{
    private UIWindow _window;

    public SidebarController SidebarController {
        get ;
        set ;
    }

    public UIViewController RootController {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public SideBarControllerTouchViewPresenter (UIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window) 
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
        _window = window;
    }

    public override void ChangePresentation (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxPresentationHint hint)
    {
        base.ChangePresentation (hint);
    }

    protected override void ShowFirstView (UIViewController viewController)
    {
        base.ShowFirstView (viewController);
    }

    protected override UINavigationController CreateNavigationController (UIViewController viewController)
    {

        var navController = new UINavigationController (viewController);
        var menuController = UIStoryboard.FromName ("storyboard", null).InstantiateViewController ("MenuTableViewController") as MenuTableViewController;
        RootController = new UIViewController ();
        SidebarController = new SidebarController (this.RootController, navController, menuController);
        return navController;
    }

    protected override void SetWindowRootViewController (UIViewController controller)
    {
        _window.AddSubview (RootController.View);
        _window.RootViewController = RootController;
    }
}
```

So thanks for getting me the rest of the way there.

Comment: I'm having an horrendous time getting this stuff to work but I'm not using XIB or Storyboards ... do I still need a custom presenter?

Answer (score 3):

For me it is working. I am not exactly sure where your problems is, but this is my code:

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
    {
        UIWindow window;

        public RootViewController RootViewController { get { return window.RootViewController as RootViewController; } }

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            var presenter = new Presenter(this, window);

            var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
            setup.Initialize();

            var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            startup.Start();

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }
    }
```

And for the rootcontroller:

```
public class RootViewController: UIViewController, IMvxCanCreateTouchView
    {
        public SidebarController SidebarController { get; private set; }
        private UIViewController root;

        public RootViewController (UIViewController root)
        {
            this.root = root;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            var menuContentView = this.CreateViewControllerFor<MenuViewModel> () as MenuViewController;
            SidebarController = new SidebarController (this, root, menuContentView) {
                MenuLocation = SidebarController.MenuLocations.Left,
                HasShadowing = false
            };
        }

        public void NavigateToView (UIViewController view)
        {
            SidebarController.ChangeContentView (new UINavigationController (view));
        }
    }
```

As a Base class for my other controllers i have this:

```
public interface IControllerWithCustomNavigation
    {
        void NavigateToView (UIViewController controller);
    }

public class BaseController<TViewModel>: MvxViewController where TViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        protected bool NavigationBarEnabled = true;

        public new TViewModel ViewModel {
            get { return (TViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
            set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        }

        public BaseController (string nib) : base (nib, null)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            if (NavigationBarEnabled) {
                NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;

                updateNavigationBar ();

                if (isRootViewModel()) {
                    addNavigationBarItemForMenu ();
                }
            } else if (NavigationController != null) {
                NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
            }
        }

        private void updateNavigationBar()
        {
            var navigationBar = NavigationController.NavigationBar;

            var colorTint = UIColor.FromRGB (133, 231, 110);
            var colorWhite = UIColor.White;

            navigationBar.BarTintColor = colorWhite;
            navigationBar.TintColor = colorTint;
            navigationBar.SetTitleTextAttributes (new UITextAttributes {
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (13, 19, 26)
            });
        }

        private bool isRootViewModel()
        {
            return NavigationController.ViewControllers.Length < 2; // Every view, even the RootView, is counted here.
        }

    private void addNavigationBarItemForMenu()
    {
        var sidebarButton = new UIBarButtonItem (
            UIImage.FromFile ("menu_icon.png"),
            UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
            (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
                (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.SidebarController.ToggleMenu();
            }
        );

        NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem (sidebarButton, true);
    }

    public virtual void NavigateToView (UIViewController controller)
    {
        (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate as AppDelegate).RootViewController.NavigateToView (controller);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the bit of code, I'll look over this. It looks as though you are using a XIB for your UI where mine is in a Storyboard. I know it shouldn't matter but that's really the only difference I can find between most of the code I find.